# Building a file with an attached library as one file

Tags: c, libcurl

I write simple software to download image file from specific url. I using libcurl, i have this code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}



int downloadFile() {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://www.example.eu/12.jpg";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "D:\\12.jpg";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }

}

int main(void) {
    downloadFile();
    return 0;
}
```

When i build project i need copy dll file to project directory, because without him i have error. Is there any way to build an exe file with a built-in library? so to have the exe itself without having to attach another file?

I count on the fact that the file will be larger but for me it is a lot easier if I have 1 file, not a few, because as I add some files now I will have 1 exe and many dll files.

Comment: Does your compiler have an option for static linking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=msvc+static+link

Comment: I use CLion with minigw

Comment: The IDE has nothing to do with this, and the compiler system also. You need to know whether the library is available for *static* linking instead of *dynamic* linking. You might have to compile this library for static linking yourself.